# Disable geolocation in selenium-chromedriver with python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

Want to disable automatic geoloaction in Chrome using Chromedriver when I visit a https website.

Tryed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.geolocation" : "2"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Both doesn't work because on every new chrome window created with chromedriver the geolocation is enabled.

Answer (score 10):

your pref key is incorrect, below code worked for me

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation" :2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for me on July 2018

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Saludos.