# Geolocation issues with selenium using python

Tags: python

How to disable the geolocation during the automation testing of url in selenium with python
or syntax in python to disable geolocaion using selenium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable geolocation in selenium-chromedriver with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244670/disable-geolocation-in-selenium-chromedriver-with-python)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.